# How to simplify the given function to obtain result?

Tags: functions

If $$f(x) = \frac{9^{x}}{9^{x}+3},$$
then find 
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2011}\right) + f\left(\frac{2}{2011}\right) + f\left(\frac{3}{2011}\right)+\dotsb +f\left(\frac{2010}{2011}\right).$$

I tried replacing $x$ by $1/x$ but end up getting a series which I was unable to simplify further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: try to see what is $f(x)+f(1-x)$?